# ASP.NET HTML Generation based on user ROLE

Tags: asp.net

I developed very simple web site, I have onle three web pages.

1. Logon.aspx
2. Register.aspx
3. MyAccount.aspx

Logon.aspx code:

```
        if (ValidateUser(email, password))
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;
            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now,
                                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3), chkPersistCookie.Checked,
                                                email + "@ticket");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
            if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
                ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

            string strRedirect;
            strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
            if (strRedirect == null)
                strRedirect = "MyAccount.aspx";
            Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("logon.aspx", true);
```

Register.aspx code:

```
    private bool RegisterUser(string name, string surname, string email, string phone, string pass)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Server\SQL;Initial Catalog=Db;Integrated Security=True; User ID=user; Password =pass;");
        conn.Open();
        string insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO Users (Email, Name, Surname, Phone, Manager, Rank, Password)
                                VALUES (@Email, @Name, @Surname, @Phone, @Manager, @Rank, @Password)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname", surname);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", phone);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Manager", "Test@Test.com");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rank", "1");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", pass);

        try
        {
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e )
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            insertQuery = string.Empty;
        }
```

Everything is perfect. 
Now what I want is on Page_Load of MyAccount.aspx:

1. Get cookie
2. Check user Role
3. Based on user Role display required web site content.

But I am not sure how to do that.

1. Should I refer cookie to establish user role?
2. How do I generate HTML based on user role?

Thanks!

Comment: Please hash your passwords rather than storing them raw!

Comment: I do hash them before. Thanks!

Comment: This is what you search for ? `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("RoleName")` ? also check that one may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880286/implementing-security-in-asp-net-web-app-as-afterthought/10880528#10880528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to go generating much HTML based on role, more like you want content within your site to be only accessible to certain roles i.e. different pages and controls. [This codeproject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication) is doing what you require.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Actually making content visible/invisible, is it secure enough?

Comment: If you mean by visible "the markup only gets sent to the client if they're in the right role" then yes, you can make that secure. If by visible you mean hiding a div etc. client side then no, that's really not very secure. Given the nature of your question I suspect the former though.

Comment: Be sure to secure your resources as well though, make sure your directories are locked down to the correct role etc.